# Does $\int_1^\infty (f(x))^2dx$ converge if $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges for positive continuous $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a positive continuous function. If $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, is it necessarily true that $\int_1^\infty (f(x))^2dx$ converges?

If it is true, explain why. If it is not true, explain with a counterexample.

I have tried many ways but failed to solve. Please assist me.

Comment: What have you tried? It is hard to help you without that information.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz-Bunjakowski? Hölder?

Comment: Have you developed any claims about the behavior of $f$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: [Find a continuous function $f:[1,\infty)\to\Bbb R $ such that $f(x) >0 $, $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx $ converges and $\int_1^\infty f(x)^2\,dx$ diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823185/find-a-continuous-function-f1-infty-to-bbb-r-such-that-fx-0-int?noredirect=1)